# Firestore Emulator multiple requests for one operation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire, firebase-tools

Can somebody please confirm that this behavior is normal for Firestore Emulator?

If not, could this be a bug?

Maybe my firestore.rules aren't set up correctly?

**When executing setDoc:**

```
const docRef = doc(this.fs, `users/${userUid}/items`, item.id);
return from(setDoc(docRef, item)).pipe(...
```

...there are the **3 requests** in the emulator

[image: emulator-requests]

...details of the requests:

**first:**

[image: first-create-request]

**second:**

[image: second-create-request]

**third:**

[image: third-create-request]

**When executing updateDoc:**

```
const docRef = doc(this.fs, `users/${userUid}/items`, update.id);
return from(updateDoc(docRef, update)).pipe(...
```

...there are the **2 requests** in the emulator

[image]

...details of the requests:

**first:**

[image: first-update-request]

**second:**

[image: second-update-request]

**SECURITY RULES:**

```
function isLoggedInUser(request) {
  return request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email_verified;
}

function isUsersOwnAccount(request, userId) {
  return request.auth.uid == userId;
}

function onlyAllowedKeysChanged(request, resource) {
  return request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly([...])
}

function atLeastOneOfKeysChanged(request, resource) {
  return request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().has Any([...])
}

match /users/{userId}/items/{itemId} {
    
allow create: if
isLoggedInUser(request)
&& isUsersOwnAccount(request, userId)
&& isValidItem(request.resource.data);
      
allow update: if
isLoggedInUser(request)
&& isUsersOwnAccount(request, userId)
&& atLeastOneOfKeysChanged(request, resource)
&& onlyAllowedKeysChanged(request, resource);
```

Comment: What leads you to believe there is a problem?  Do the code and rules ultimately not behave the way you expect, regardless of what you see in the log?  If you do believe there to be a problem, file a bug report on [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) with your observations and the behavior that doesn't work the way you expect.